# Application Request Routing use with WCF Restful web services

Tags: wcf, arr

Anybody done with the Application Request Routing use with WCF Restful web services?

The requirement is, from the mobile application, invokes webservices URLs. But the reverse proxy needs to route the request to actual server. Can anybody suggest a soultion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it. Please refer the following link for further reference.

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx